# Why does this init.d script sometimes not run at shutdown?

Tags: debian, mysql, init-script, sysvinit

I'm on Debian 10 Buster.

I can't figure out what's wrong with this init.d script? Sometimes it doesn't run at server shutdown.

My MySQL `error_log` fills up with "Status information" when the server reboots due to `SIGHUP`. Here is a link describing this behavior: [MySQL Server response to SIGHUP signals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/unix-signal-response.html)

This init.d script [/etc/init.d/mysql](https://pastebin.com/raw/84fjNfh7) I'm using was taken directly from the [official MySQL release deb](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/) with a couple minor modifications by myself, which are documented in the file.

And here is the [sourced mysql-helpers file](https://pastebin.com/raw/BEkhtPxh) referenced by the init.d script.

Stopping/starting/restarting MySQL at runtime *never* produces the SIGHUP, but sometimes the script chokes with no logging info. The .pid is gone, but MySQL silently fails to start.

The frustrating part is it *sometimes* runs at shutdown and sometimes not. It is random; 75% it doesn't run, 25% it does run.

Another part of this question could be, *Does anyone know where to find a working init.d script for MySQL 5.7.37 on Debian 10?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you dont try to use systemd to manage daemons, its easier and available since debian Jessie.
/etc/systemd/system/servicemysql.service

```
[Unit]
Description=MySQL task
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=reboot.target
Before=poweroff.target halt.target shutdown.target
Requires=poweroff.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/path/to/your/script.sh
ExecReload=/usr/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=shutdown.target
```

Dont forget to give 0644 permissions to this file and after every modification run:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

then to enable the daemon run:

```
systemctl enable <name of the service>
```

and to start it run:

```
systemctl start <name of the service>
```

For checking if the service is running execute:

```
systemctl status <name of the service>
```

Comment: Does systemd still require using the init.d script? Does using `systemctl` replace the `service` command? e.g. `service mysql restart` is the same as `systemctl mysql restart`? Getting desperate, so I may just try it.

Comment: Yes i forgot to tell you, the equivalence  is `systemctl <command> mysql.service` in your case `systemctl restart mysql.service` see `--help` or `man` for more info but the script should be located in /etc/systemd/system not in init.d path so i recommend to delete the old service from there

Comment: You're welcome. After all init.d facilities are not so "fáciles". Here's more useful info about some config vars and how to use if the daemon still not working.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38072849/when-should-the-option-remainafterexit-needs-to-be-set-true-when-creating-new-sy#:~:text=RemainAfterExit%3D%20Takes%20a%20boolean%20value,flag%20is%20set%20to%20true. https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

Comment: As I  mencioned in my answer after every update/change in the config file if the service you should do `systemctl daemon-reload ` then the `systemd` equivalent for update-rc.d is `systemctl enable MySQL.service`. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi,  `/etc/init.d` is a deprecated form of running services from SystemVInit that is included in some system services and still included in old daemons. Today, exclusively with `Systemd` is possible to manage and run your services only editing your script on `/etc/systemd/system`  So you don't have to work   on `/etc/init.d`  only on  `/etc/systemd/system`                 
 More info related in: https://askubuntu.com/questions/911525/difference-between-systemctl-init-d-and-service